# Designing a writer for different file formats in C# (interface vs. class vs. abstract class)

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class

In a C# application I have an array of strings like this:

`string[] myArray = GetStrings(source);`

Now I would like to write the content of this array to a file in different formats as e.g.

- flat list
- CSV
- XML
- ...

However I'm unsure what would be the most adequate way of implementing these different formats. I could think of:

1. One class per format, each with a `Write()` method:

   - `FlatListWriter`
   - `CsvWriter`
   - `XmlWriter`
2. One class containing several methods:

   - `WriteAsFlatList()`
   - `WriteAsCsv()`
   - `WriteAsXml()`
3. An interface with a `Write()` method and its implementing classes like in 1.
4. Some kind of abstract class.

What would you recommend?

Comment: You missed the option of interfaces for objects to save themselves in the desired format (be it csv, xml, edifact, ansi x12, something else)...

Comment: @RowlandShaw Could you provide a link or something? Your comment sounds interesting but I don't know where to start.

Comment: It's more for the case when you have a collection of objects, rather than strings - in essence, it's the case of "model the data, not the file format" - your collection of strings *might* represent an invoice line, so it's better modelled as an invoice line that can be clever about how it's persisting, and gives a more general purpose approach than hoping that all your arrays of strings represent invoice lines when saving as CSV, for example.

Answer (score 2):

All of your options look reasonable and equally good. The choise shoud be based on the other requirements for your system.

If you want to add formats in the future, and multiple people will write them, then one class per writer seems a better option, as they would be better separated, you can load them dynamically and test independently.

If you want to call these methods from some powershell script, multiple static methods in the same class may be a simpler and more convinient solution.

Comment: As it is a very small tool I don't think that multiple people will extend it but me :-) So I think your hint going for the second option looks reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is a small tool from personal experience I have found that it is better to separate the things into its own class. If you need to add some features it will save you some time in doing so.

It also sets itself up for better unit tests which is a best practice that I have picked up to do in almost any tool I write. It leads to better code and saves me time in testing my application and the separate classes for each writer will help you in this if you write unite tests. Read [Roy Osherove's Blog](http://artofunittesting.com/) on some more tips on this.

Hope this advice helps.